# How to use WITH clause and ref cursor in stored procedure in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to use WITH within a stored procedure?

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_CSV(
        CUR_USERS OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
CUR_JOBS OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
    AS
    BEGIN
    WITH resultset2 AS
      (SELECT U.USERID,
        U.PASSWORD
      FROM USERS U
      WHERE TRUNC(DATECREATED)=TRUNC(SYSDATE-1)
      )
    SELECT RESULTSET2.* FROM resultset2;
    OPEN CUR_USERS FOR SELECT * FROM QUOTE WHERE LOWER(CREATEDBY)= resultset2.USERID;
OPEN CUR_JOBS FOR SELECT * FROM JOBS WHERE LOWER(CREATEDBY)= resultset2.USERID;
    END;
```

With the above code I am getting below error-

```
•   Error(6,1): PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement 
•   Error(13,22): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored 
•   Error(13,72): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "RESULTSET2"."USERID": invalid identifier
```

Can we store the results in a temporary table and drop the table after use? if yes then how can we achieve that? If No, then what is the other solution? I am using oracle 11g.

The sample code will really be appreciated...
Keep Coding :)

Comment: The issue is not the `with`.  You haven't specified where the results are stored.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can we store the results in a temporary table and drop the table after use? if **yes** then how can we achieve that? If **No**, then what is the other solution? I am using oracle 11g.

Comment: You don't need a temporary table. Just store it in a variable.

Comment: Aren't you over-complicating things? Basically you have a JOIN query between two tables or a sub-query on a second table. Or are you simply trying to see if you can use WITH in a PL/SQL stored procedure?

Answer (score -1):

There doesn't seem to be support for the WITH clause on PL/SQL stored procedures, functions, or packages, but you could use it in a dynamic SQL statement with execute immediate, as shown [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/with-clause-enhancements-12cr1).